# TabLayout with ViewPager2 is not displaying the corresponding fragments in the ViewPager2 and app freezes

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am trying to display news of different categories under different tabs using TabLayout. The corresponding fragments do not load at all, only the tabs are displayed. The app freezes when I try to scroll or select a tab such that even the tabIndicator barely moves to the corresponding tab and Android displays "Not responding" message.

> **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    NewsPagerAdapter newsPagerAdapter;
    TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator;
    String[] tabTitles = new String[]{"HOME","BUSINESS","HEALTH","TECHNOLOGY","SPORTS"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tbCustom);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tlCategories); setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.vpNews);
        newsPagerAdapter = new NewsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getLifecycle());
        viewPager2.setAdapter(newsPagerAdapter);



        tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, (tab, position) -> tab.setText(tabTitles[position]));
        tabLayoutMediator.attach();

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                newsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        tabLayoutMediator.detach();
        viewPager2.setAdapter(null);
    }
}
```

> **NewsPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class NewsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public NewsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0: return new HomeFragment();
            case 1: return new BusinessFragment();
            case 2: return new HealthFragment();
            case 3: return new TechnologyFragment();
            case 4: return new SportsFragment();
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

> **Home Fragment.java** - Other fragments have the same structure

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    private List<NewsModelClass> homeNews = new ArrayList<>();
    String country = "in";
    String category = "general";
    int pageSize = 50;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
    final String API_KEY = "ba88d060a3e049ca9fa46f2bea0d52c4";

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.rvHome);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getContext(),homeNews);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
        fetchNews();
    }

    private void fetchNews()
    {
         Call<NewsArticles> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getMyApi().getNews(country,pageSize,category,API_KEY);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsArticles>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<NewsArticles> call, @NonNull Response<NewsArticles> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (!homeNews.isEmpty()) {
                        homeNews.clear();
                    }
                    homeNews=response.body().getArticles();
                    newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<NewsArticles> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Something is wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

> **fragment_home.xml** - Other fragments have the same layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rvHome"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:padding="8dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

> **NewsAdapter.java**

```
public class NewsAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<NewsModelClass> allNews;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context,List<NewsModelClass> 
    allNews) {
        this.context = context;
        this.allNews = allNews;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View newsItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_news, parent, false);
    return new NewsViewHolder(newsItem);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {

    NewsModelClass currentNewsItem = allNews.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(currentNewsItem.getTitle());
    holder.author.setText(currentNewsItem.getAuthor());
    if (currentNewsItem.getUrlToImage() != null)
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(Uri.parse(currentNewsItem.getUrlToImage())).into(holder.articleImage);

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        String newsUrl = currentNewsItem.getUrl();

        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

        int colorInt = Color.parseColor("#F1ECC3");
        CustomTabColorSchemeParams defaultColors = new CustomTabColorSchemeParams.Builder()
                .setToolbarColor(colorInt)
                .build();
        builder.setDefaultColorSchemeParams(defaultColors);

        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(newsUrl));
    });



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return allNews.size();
}


public static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView articleImage;
    TextView title, author;
    CardView cardView;

    public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        articleImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivArticleImage);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeadline);
        author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAuthor);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is ot working fine if you remove all  fetch() calls?

Comment: @gioravered No. I commented all the fetch() calls and it still behaves the same :(

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop maybe.. Hard to tell without debugging.

Comment: @gioravered Yes you are right! The instantiation tabLayoutMediator is in an infinite loop. Any idea why it is happening? As far as I could see, that line executes and gradually the corresponding fragments are created and then the control shifts to instantiation of tabLayoutMediator again and gets stuck in a loop. Any idea why this is happening and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Not sure. Try to remove viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()) & tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position))?

Comment: Hey! I removed newsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in  tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener and my tabs are working fine! I guess the datasetchanged callback returns the control to tablayoutmediator to update the new tabs ;when there are none infinitely!

Comment: Great news. Good luck!